# Experience with direct data access components

Tags: mysql, delphi, mydac

I would like to know as to what has been the experience of using direct data access components like devart's MyDAC which allows a direct connection to the mysql server rather than through the client library or ODBC.

Answer (score 4):

With [AnyDAC](http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/) you can acess almost all popular databases (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Firebird, PostgreSQL, DB2, SQLite, ...). High-speed native direct access, many unique futures, unified API for access to cross-database features, excelent support.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used MyDAC before. My experience is with DAC for MySQL from http://www.microolap.com/.

So far so good. Pretty easy to drop onto my Delphi projects, set the values of various properties, and then ready to connect. It has quite a number of useful components that allows you to retrieve data in several ways and you can use it easily with TDataSource.

No issues with deployment as well. All compiled nicely into one EXE.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

[Mydac](http://www.devart.com/mydac) is the best when you try to connect to MySql, it's fast stable and real powerful components.

Also the same for other components like Sdac and Odac.

and if you would like to use more than database you can use [Unidac](http://www.devart.com/unidac), which you can use to connect to (oracle, Sql server, Mysql, Interbase, Firebird and ODBC drivers.).

Another great point for [Devart](http://www.devart.com) components that you don't need client library to be installed on the clients machine (libmysql.dll).

Comment: I believe bypassing the standard DB client library is often a minus, not a plus, unless you have a very good reason to do so. You rely wholly on a third party implementation that could have flaws, especially security ones, and may be less tested and updated than the standard client, and not implementing all the available features. At least the MySQL protocol is open source, but others DB may not, and I would be very careful to choose that approach just to simplify deployment.

Comment: ldsandon, I have using MyDac and Odac with direct mode since years, and never faced any problem, DevArt is good company to rely on, maybe you are right for other components.

Comment: Am thinking of using MyDAC for accessing MySQL Server